# What is the joke about Frampton Comes Alive in Wayne's World 2?

Tags: peter-frampton

In *Wayne's World 2*, there is a moment when Wayne and Cassandra are discussing about Cassandra's old records:

> CASSANDRE: Isn't that great? You've heard it?
>   WAYNE: Have I seen this one before? ***Frampton Comes Alive*? Everybody in the world has *Frampton Comes Alive***. If you lived in the suburbs you were issued it. It came in the mail with samples of "Tide".

I don't know much about this artist, except his famous hit *Baby, I love your way* so I didn't know he was so famous that "Everybody in the world has *Frampton Comes Alive*". Or is this irony and nobody cared about this album?

So what is the joke about Peter Frampton's album?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This entire answer is from the perspective of someone who was 15 when this album was released - right in the target audience at the time for such an album.*

The joke is actually in the exaggeration, rather than the statement itself.
That everybody in the US received a free copy in the mail along with other spam is just part of that exaggeration.

[Frampton Comes Alive!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frampton_Comes_Alive!) was a colossal international hit, yet appeared to come from nowhere. At the time no-one [of our age group, ref above] really knew who he was or where he came from. After a while we discovered he used to be in 'Humble Pie' & 'The Herd' but we weren't quite sure who they were either.
There was no Google in 1976.

And yes, at the time, it did seem that absolutely everybody had a copy. Even your parents would like it - which would ordinarily be ***a bad thing***.
You would hear it played wherever you went; parties, supermarkets, every radio station... it became hard to get away from after a while.

It was possibly the world's first 'coffee table album' [complete opinion on my part, no evidence.]

For me "Show Me the Way" was the big breakthrough single from it.

From the first couple of paragraphs of the Wikipedia p[age...

> Frampton Comes Alive! is a double live album by English rock musician
>   Peter Frampton released in 1976. It is one of the best-selling live
>   albums in the United States, and considered by many to be one of the
>   finest live rock recordings of all time. Following four solo albums
>   with little commercial success, Frampton Comes Alive! was a
>   breakthrough for the artist.
>
> Released on January 6, 1976, it debuted on the charts at 191. The
>   album reached number one on the Billboard 200 the week ending April
>   10, 1976, and was in the top spot for a total of 10 weeks. It was the
>   best-selling album of 1976, selling over 8 million copies in the US
>   and becoming one of the best-selling live albums to date, with
>   estimated sales of 11 million worldwide.
>
> Frampton Comes Alive! was voted "Album of the year" in the 1976
>   Rolling Stone readers poll. It stayed on the chart for 97 weeks and
>   was still No. 14 on Billboard's 1977 year-end album chart.

Personal opinion as to why it never had a famous follow-up... by 1977 the UK was ruled by Punk & no-one would even admit to owning Comes Alive any more, let alone buy the next one.

Comment: Remember when 15 year old people was target audience for rock music? Pepperidge farm remembers.

Comment: target audience for 'rock' was 15 - 25 iirc at the time, so yes, we were lower end of the range, but still in it. The 'Pepperidge farm' reference means nothing to me, I had to Google what it was. Never heard of it in the UK.

Comment: It became a [meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pepperidge-farm-remembers) on remembering good old days :)

Comment: AH, OK; I get it - though it never crossed the 'pond'. Not a known product over here.